# Running this bash script ONCE causes a "System program problem detected" on EVERY reboot

Tags: networking, bash, crash, dnsmasq, hostapd

I'm trying to create a script which, when run, will **set up a WiFi network over which two or more devices can communicate**. If I run the current version of this script **once**, it causes that device to display a **"System program problem detected"** popup on **every** subsequent reboot.

At present, this is an irritation rather than catastrophe. However, given that, in future, I may well be running this script on dozens of devices, the situation is sub-optimal!

This is the bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Install required software.
sudo apt install dnsmasq
sudo apt install hostapd
sudo systemctl stop dnsmasq
sudo systemctl stop hostapd

# Configure a static IP.
if ! python3 edit_dhcpcd_config.py ; then
  exit 1
fi

# Configure the DHCP server.
if [ ! -f /etc/dnsmasq.conf.orig ]; then
  sudo mv /etc/dnsmasq.conf /etc/dnsmasq.conf.orig
fi
if ! python3 edit_dnsmasq_config.py ; then
  exit 1
fi
if ! sudo systemctl start dnsmasq ; then
  exit 1
fi

# Configure the access point host software.
if ! python3 edit_hostapd_conf.py ; then
  exit 1
fi
if ! python3 edit_daemon_conf.py ; then
  exit 1
fi

# Start it up.
if ! sudo systemctl unmask hostapd ; then
  exit 1
fi
if ! sudo systemctl enable hostapd ; then
  exit 1
fi
if ! sudo systemctl start hostapd ; then
  exit 1
fi

echo "Mother network set up successfully."

# Check everything's up.
#sudo systemctl status hostapd
#sudo systemctl status dnsmasq
```

The various **Python scripts** called in the above are just snippets of code, which either append to or replace various dnsmasq and hostapd config files. I'm happy to post these files if requested.

Comment: This actually a notification of a crash. Please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -l /var/crash/`

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll do as you say as soon as I get into work tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a notification that a crash has happened on your system. Although in most cases this is not serious, you can check what crashed by reading the output of `ls -l /var/crash/`.

If you recognize the crash reason to be something in your script, you should modify your script and try again.

If however you decide to disable crash reporting altogether, then please follow the instructions below so no more crash reports will be displayed in the future.

---

You can disable crash reporting if that is what you want by editing the file `/etc/default/apport` and changing `enabled=1` to `enabled=0` and saving the file.

Alternatively you can do this from your script by adding this line:

```
sudo sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/g' /etc/default/apport
```

Best of luck

Comment: Your answer was excellent. However, the problem was caused by the OP (me) being an idiot, rather than anything deeper! Sorry about that.

Comment: @TomHosker You are most welcome. Mistakes happen, that's why debugging exists.  : )

Answer (score 0):

It now seems this problem was caused by a simple error on my part, rather than anything deeper. As I was testing whether the "System program problem detected" popup was still occurring, **I was running `reboot` from the command line**. Some windows - usually Chromium - were still open when I ran this, and thus had to close more quickly than they would have liked. Once I closed all open windows before rebooting, the popups stopped appearing.